# Python exception ordering

Tags: python, python-2.x

Just curious, why does the following code

```
import sys
class F(Exception):
    sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    pass

sys.stderr.write('Before Exception\n')
sys.stderr.flush()

try:
    raise F
except F:
    pass
```

output:

```
Inside exception
Before Exception
```

and not:

```
Before exception
Inside Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sven rightly said, class bodies are executed immediately when the class definition is executed.

In your code, your definition of your class F is above this command `sys.stderr.write('Before Exception\n')` and hence this `sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')` gets executed first and consequently its output is seen first.

As a test, run this program -

```
import sys

sys.stderr.write('Before Exception\n')
sys.stderr.flush()

class F(Exception):
    sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    pass

try:
    raise F
except F:
    pass
```

The output now you will get is -

```
Before exception
Inside Exception
```

This is simply because the statement `sys.stderr.write('Before Exception\n')` gets executed before the class definition gets executed.

Infact, the printing of `Inside Exception` has nothing to do with your initializing an instance of F (by using `raise`). It will get printed no matter you initialize an instance of F or not.

Try this -

```
import sys

class F(Exception):
    sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    pass
```

Still you will get this output -

```
Inside Exception
```

although you have not made an instance of the class F.

Answer (score 8):

You're printing in the class, not its initialization block . Try running this

```
import sys
class F(Exception):
    sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    pass
```

alone. i.e., it's not running when you call `raise F`.   Try this instead

```
import sys
class F(Exception):
    def __init__():
        sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
        sys.stderr.flush()

raise new F()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have statements at the class level:

```
class F(Exception):
    sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
```

consider this, which will not be executed until you create an object instance:

```
class F(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        sys.stderr.write('Inside exception\n')
```